# 'unsuccessful metadata update' error on creating view

Tags: sql, firebird

Can anyone tell me why this does not work. I get an 'unsuccessful metadata update' error. The select statement works with no issues, only when I add the create view that I get the error.

```
CREATE VIEW V_DJ_BASELINESTART
(
 JOBNUMBER,
 MILESTONE,
 ACTUALSTARTDATE,
 MILESTONEID
) AS 
       select  j.job_number AS JOBNUMBER, m.milestone_name AS MILESTONE, sm.actual_start_date AS ACTUALSTARTDATE,
m.milestone_ID AS MILESTONEID
from job j inner join schedule s on
s.Job_number = j.job_number inner join schedule_milestone sm on
sm.schedule_id = s.schedule_id inner join milestone m on
m.milestone_id = sm.milestone_id
where m.milestone_ID = '8';
```

Comment: An 'unsuccessful metadata update' error usually contains more information. Could you post the full error.

Comment: Now I get an error that says unsuccessful metedata error table V_DJ_BASELINESTARTDATE already exists.

Comment: But I can't see it in the Views list and I can't query from it?

Answer (score 1):

The view already exists (as explained [here](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq319/)).

Use `ALTER VIEW` or use a different name.

Comment: or  `CREATE OR ALTER VIEW`